# Update element in DynamoDB from API Gateway AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-api-gateway

I'm requesting and managing a dynamoDb from the AmzonWebService.

I would update my element with new datas.

This is how I do :

```
  {
"TableName": "Strips",
  "Key": {
        "StripId": {
            "S": "$input.path('$.StripId')"
        }
    },
    "UpdateExpression": "set SessionId =  "$input.path('$.SessionId')"
    "ReturnValues": "ALL_NEW"
}
```

I have this error message and my element on my DB is not updated.

> endpoint response body before transformations:
>   {"__type":"com.amazon.coral.service#SerializationException"}

EDIT: This is the objet I'm using in my request body :

```
{
"StripId":"f58b6811-5a11-4a53-84d3-19bf42dd8fef",
"SessionId":"9fc6f591-e805-4113-b673-d596736b2ff3"
}
```

Does anyone know why ?

Comment: The values for key attributes are mandatory. Check whether $input has the expected values.

Comment: I have edited my question @notionquest

Answer (score 1):

Please use the below:-

I have added `ExpressionAttributeValues` to provide value for `SessionId`.

```
{
  "TableName": "Strips",
  "Key": {
        "StripId": {
            "S": "$input.path('$.StripId')"
        }
    },
    "UpdateExpression": "set SessionId =  :sessionIdVal"
    "ExpressionAttributeValues" : {
        ":sessionIdVal": $input.path('$.SessionId'),
    },
    "ReturnValues": "ALL_NEW"
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @notionquest , I still have the SerializationException when I'm using your code. I'm editing my question to show you which object I'm using for my test in the request body.